# eclipse cannot find class in jar for google api client

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a project that uses google calendar. I built the original code in a separate project that used maven.

This is the maven artifact:

> ```
> <dependency>
>      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
>      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
>      <version>1.22.0</version>
>  </dependency>
> ```

Works just fine.

I then import the code into another project that doesn't use maven.
I go to the maven website and download THIS SAME JAR.
I go to `Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Add External Jars` and add this jar.

I go `Project -> Clean` and build the project.

The result? Classes such as: `com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore` and `com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory`

CANNOT BE RESOLVED!

I know they are in the jar because I just used it with maven!

Any help on this?

Comment: Can you check in marker view what are the unresolved problems?

Comment: DataStoreFactory cannot be resolved to a type Cal.java line 35 Java Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this problem because `google-api-client`  requires

> Google HTTP Client Library for Java
>
> Google OAuth Client Library for Java

You did not face this problem in maven as maven downloaded them for you internally. Maven resolves transitive dependencies ie (dependencies that are required for your jar) internally. You did not see that coming.

**You can download both from here :**

[google-http-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.22.0)

[google-oauth-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.22.0)

Have a look at maven's dependency resolution mechanism [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Have a look here to get idea of the required dependencies for your current api to work:

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/tree/c7421ae143c45b3e75c2bd6dcc86eba0d39bcf59#dependencies

Comment: that was it. for a complete list of all dependencies I simply went to my .m2 local repository and copied all the libraries from google.